# Why do HTML5 features like localStorage and sessionStorage work in IE7 Emulator mode in IE11?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, session-storage, ie-compatibility-mode

In Internet Explorer 11, I turn on IE7 Mode and test sessionStorage. I do

```
sessionStorage.put("someObject",someObject);
```

and then do

```
if(sessionStorage != null) {
        console.log(sessionStorage.get("someObject"));
}   

console.log(sessionStorage.get("someObject"));
```

It actually prints the value of the object out. Why is this?