# IE 11 - HTML5 form validation with a HTML4.01 DOCTYPE

Tags: html, validation, doctype

On an old project we use this doctype and this meta :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
```

My problem is with IE11 (and certainly IE10) the HTML5 form validation submission process is launched.

For example on a field the `maxLength` is 5, for some reason once `blur` event is detected some javascript format it (12345 --> 12 345). The length becomes 6 and so IE11 on submit shows the field with a red border.

- I know we can use `novalidation`
- I know the javascript formatting could be re-thought
- I know we could increase the maxlength to match the formatted text and limit typing with javascript.

But what I don't know is why HTML5 validation is running since we're not using HTML5 doctype?

Comment: The doctype doesn't actually have any effect on what sort of JavaScript APIs the browser will support on a given page. It only tells the browser what HTML/CSS rendering mode to use (in this case [almost standards mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325)). As for IE7 emulation mode, a related question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022370/why-do-html5-features-like-localstorage-and-sessionstorage-work-in-ie7-emulator

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks. I tried removing IE7 emulation mode same effects, so my best bet is to advise to add novalidation in all forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we ended up adding a script in the footer template used in every pages to add `novalidate` to form inputs :

```
<script>
    for(var f=document.forms,i=f.length;i--;) { 
      f[i].setAttribute("novalidate","");
    }
</script>
```